# how to connect pgadmin container to host system localhost postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker, containers, database-connection, pgadmin-4

I pulled pgAdmin4 docker image into my linux debian machine and followed the process specified [here](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/container_deployment.html) to configure the container. I run `docker run -p 8000:8000 --env-file ./pgadmin_docker_env.list -d dpage/pgadmin4`. For clarity, the pgadmin_docker_env.list specified in the command contains the environmental variables:: `PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=my_email@example.com PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=my_password`. With the container running in detached mode, I run localhost:8080 in my web browser to access pgAdmin 4 in server mode. However, I was unable to create a server connection to the localhost postgres database from inside the pgadmin. I got the following error after input of the connection parameters (shown in the screenshot attached below)
[image]
`Unable to connect to server: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?`

UPDATE
I used host.docker.internal in place of localhost but I still got an error

```
Unable to connect to server: could not translate host name "host.docker.internal" to address: Name does not resolve
```

Comment: Which `localhost` are you trying to connect to?  (The host system outside a container; the pgadmin container; a separate PostgreSQL container; my laptop?  All of these things individually think they are `localhost`)

Comment: The host system localhost

Answer (score 2):

`localhost` in this scenario refers to the PgAdmin container, where there is not a Postgres instance running.

You want to connect to Postgres running on the host machine from the container (from what I can tell anyway?) so use `host.docker.internal` instead of `localhost`.

Answer (score 2):

You can skip a step if you've already done it

1. Using psql, alter the authentication credential of default postgres user, postgres with the following commands

```
sudo -u postgres psql
ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'newPassword';
```

Optionally, you can also create a user for your current account as a superuser with `CREATE ROLE user_name WITH LOGIN SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE REPLICATION;`

2. Modify /etc/postgresql/13/main/pg_hba.conf and add
   `host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5` to the end of the file
3. Modify the pgadmin_docker_env.list file to include your choice port

```
PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=8000
```

4. Stop the previously running container pgadmin `docker stop pgadmin` and remove the container`docker rm pgadmin`. Then run `docker run --env-file ./pgadmin_docker_env.list --network="host" --name pgadmin dpage/pgadmin4` to run the container in host network mode. See [more on host network mode](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/)
5. Run localhost:8000 in your web browser and create a server connection using the same connection parameter as in the screenshot.

Comment: (Note that host networking does not work on MacOS or Windows systems; the option is accepted but networking in and out of the container silently fails.)

Comment: Yeah, the solution was tested on a Linux Debian machine.